# prove that if $\varphi\Longrightarrow\psi$ then there is an elementary proposition Q in both propositions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove that if $\varphi\Longrightarrow\psi$ then

- $\varphi$ is a contradiction or
- $\psi$ is a tautology or
- There is an elementary proposition Q in both propositions

The first and second are fairly easy, as $\varphi\Longrightarrow\psi \leftrightarrow \varphi\rightarrow\psi$ and the last proposition is a tautology if either $\varphi$ is a contradiction or $\psi$ is a tautology.

I'm having some trouble proving the last part I tried assuming that there isn't such a Q and then showing that in such a case there is model $M$ where $M(\varphi)=T$ while $M(\psi)=F$ but it seems wrong as I can find model M where there is no Q proposition and $M(\varphi)=T$ while $M(\psi)=T$. I understand that the question asks to prove such Q exists when $\varphi\Longrightarrow\psi$ i.e if $M|=\varphi$ then $M|=\psi$ and there is a proposition Q but I don't know how I can show that such a proposition exists in this situation

Comment: If you are satisfied by the answer below, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi$ is not a contradiction, then you can assign truth values to the elementary propositions in $\phi$ that make $\phi$ true. If $\psi$ is not a tautology, then you can assign truth values to the elementary propositions in $\psi$ that make $\psi$ false.  But then, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ have no elementary propositions in common, you can put together your two assignments to get an assignment that make $\phi \Rightarrow \psi$ false. So if $\phi \Rightarrow \psi$ is true (i.e., it holds under every assignment), then at least one of the statements:

- $\varphi$ is a contradiction or
- $\psi$ is a tautology or
- There is an elementary proposition Q in both propositions

must be false.

Comment: but I can also do that when $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have an elementary proposition in common, also I need to prove that if $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ then they have a proposition in common

Comment: I have expanded on the explanation in my answer. I hope that helps.